# Redmine user controller hooks in plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine-plugins

I want to write a plugin for redmine. in this plugin i want to limit number of user registration.
How can i hook redmine user controller to do this limitation? I don't want to change core redmine code. for example:

```
if User.count = 10
  do_something
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should determine what exactly action you would like to patch. After this you can add `before_filter` or use [`alias_method_chain`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Module/alias_method_chain) or rewrite method (it is the WORST way) in your plugin. Your patch will influence on the Redmine core.

Some additional info:

- how to write plugins - [official tutorial](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugin_Tutorial)
- list of plugins (to see some working examples) - [official](http://www.redmine.org/plugins) or try to find on github